# Operation only on filter elements of chr array

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I have these simple program which convert number to binary.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int value = 007755 ;

    string binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2);

    Console.WriteLine(binary);

    //Convert to char array
    char[] binary_array = binary.ToCharArray(); 



    // List all elements
    for (int i = 0; i < binary_array.Length; i++)
    {               

        char letter = binary_array[i];

        Console.Write("Element " + i + ": ");
        Console.Write(letter);          
    }           

}
```

I must have some operations on that "elements" of array which has "1" value. How can I do that? I try something like these:

```
if(binary_array[i]==1){
 //Some operations
}
```

but these not work on char element. I think I can convert that char element to int, but How do that simple?

Comment: The digits 0 to 9 when converted to a string are ASCII 0x30 to 0x39.

Comment: You could a [BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.-ctor) (e.g, `var bits = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));`) and test the bits at specific indexes (e.g., if `(bits[10]) { // do something }` <= stores booleans instead of `1`/`0`). See also the [BitVector32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32) struct (depending on what you're about to do with those tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `binary_array` is an array of chars, not an array of ints.

The easiest thing to do would be:

```
if (binary_array[i] == '1')
```

That is, test its value against the char `'1'`.

Alternatively, you could turn your char array into an array of ints with:

```
int[] int_array = binary_array.Select(x => x - '0').ToArray();
```

or:

```
int[] int_array = binary_array.Select(x => x == '1' : 1 : 0).ToArray();
```

or:

```
int[] int_array = binary_array.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Or you could turn it into an array of bools with:

```
bool[] bool_array = binary_array.Select(x => x == '1').ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I try "1", so that's the problem.